# Getting bad date on Grails Prod App

Tags: date, grails

I have a production application made with Grails 2.2.4 that was deployed some weeks ago, in that app I have a domain class like this:

> class Date{
>
> ```
> Date mDate;
> static constraints = {
>     mDate(nullable:false, blank:false, max: new Date());
> }
> ```
>
> }

Desired behavior:
When a user creates an object from this class, the attribute mDate should not be greater than today's date.

Real behavior:
When the user tries to create an object, the application tells her that the attribute mDate should not be greater than the deployed date.

Example:

Deployed date: 01/Aug/2015

User tries to create an object with the attribute mDate = 02/Aug/2015, then the system complains it shouldn't be greater than 01/Aug/2015.

What is happening?

Comment: The server's date is correct.
I use Tomcat on prod.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails only evaluates constraints once and then uses the same value. This is problematic when using `new Date()` instead of a constant value.

In the Grails docs under [*Declaring Constraints*](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/validation.html#constraints):

> Note that constraints are only evaluated once which may be relevant for a constraint that relies on a value like an instance of java.util.Date.

```
class User {
    ...
    static constraints = {
        // this Date object is created when the constraints are evaluated, not
        // each time an instance of the User class is validated.
        birthDate max: new Date()
    }
}
```

Instead, use a custom validator:

```
class User {
    ...
    static constraints = {
        birthDate validator: { it < new Date() }
    }
}
```